# Remove CherryPy before_finalize hook from response

Tags: python, cherrypy

I've got an existing application where I would like to remove a `@cherrypy.tools.expires()` from the hooks to be run on `before_finalize`.

What I have:

1. A controller that has a `GET` that is decorated with `@cherrypy.tools.expires()`
2. Some wrapper around all controllers/handlers that checks to see if a user is authenticated or not. If not authenticated, an 401 Not Authorized error is raised instead of calling the `GET`
3. The CherryPy error handler or something along those lines, assumes control

It is in step 3 that I need to remove the `before_finalize` hook, because even-though the wrapper never executed the `GET`, it is still added to the global `request` object.

I know that I can find the tools in `cherrypy.serving.request.hooks` however there is no easy way to figure out which hook is the right one because they are not named.

Other than iterating over the hooks and doing some guessing based upon the function name, is there a good way to figure out which one I want to remove?

Comment: So why did you add this hook to your handler method?

Comment: @webKnjaZ because it is an code-base I am inheriting, and it is used all over the place, unlike Pyramid which I am familiar with, these hooks seem to be global for the request, so even when the handler raises an error, the expiration headers are still sent. In my exception handling code I now remove the `before_finalize` hooks.

Comment: I think you can override and disable this tool on the class basis

Comment: Could you please provide the full code snippet?

Comment: Here's what I mean `class YourClass(ClassYouInherit):  _cp_config = {'tools.expires.on': False}`

Comment: I can't distribute the code, and I am not familiar enough with the code base to dumb it down.

Comment: I had a Controller that had a GET handler that was decorated with @cherrypy.tools.expires(), that GET handler was never called because a wrapper that wrapped the pipeline was raising a NotAuthorized error (if the user was not logged in), that was caught by the error handler somewhere, which then provided a 401 Not Authorized response. However it would still set the expires header because the tool was added to the current global request object. My error handler was a function, there is no class to disable the tool other than to loop over hooks and remove it that way.

Comment: oh.. I see, in this case it is very tricky approach. I wouldn't go for it. You could probably just remove that `Expires` header from the request object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does work, but this just seems... wrong:

```
# Remove any hooks that happen to contain "expires" in the callback's name
hooks = cherrypy.serving.request.hooks['before_finalize']
hooks = filter(lambda hook: 'expires' not in str(hook.callback), hooks)
cherrypy.serving.request.hooks['before_finalize'] = hooks
```